# PyQt: "AttributeError: 'PlayerWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'" when opening second window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am coding a GUI using `PyQt5`. At some point I am trying to open secondary windows from the main window. My second windows are a class `PlayerWindow.PlayerWindow` inheriting from `QWidget`. The lines of code opening the windows are:

```
newWindow = PlayerWindow.PlayerWindow( self.playerUrl)
newWindow.show()
newWindow.exec_()
```

The code behaves the way I want it to behave, but I get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'PlayerWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'

How could I avoid that?

Comment: exec_() is a function of QCoreApplication, you need to instanciate a QApplication for example

Comment: @λuser: I am instantiating a QApplication for the main window. Should I instantiate a new one of every new window?

Comment: sorry no, you should only have one instance of `QApplication`, but `exec_` is not a method of `QWidget`, but of `QApplication`: `qApp.exec_()`

Comment: `exec_()` is for modal widgets, e.g., dialogs - it takes control until that widget is closed. I am guessing you are not doing that, so `show()` alone will be sufficient and you can simply remove `exec_()`.

Comment: @mdurant: If I only have `show()` the windows opens and closes instantaneously. That's what bugs me, the ugly way of adding `exec()` makes it work. How can I get the window to only close when manually closed?

Comment: @mdurant: I just checked, replacing `exec` by any line causing an exception works It's like the window does not get garbage collected after the error...

Comment: You must store the reference to the window somewhere to avoid collection and destruction, perhaps `self.player = newWindow`

Comment: @mdurant: Yeah it just hit me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found my error.
the window gets garbage collected if not stored as an attribute of the main window instance. So changing to:

```
self.newWindow = PlayerWindow.PlayerWindow( self.playerUrl)
self.newWindow.show()
```

The `exec` line caused an exception forbidding the garbage collection.